# How to add parameters when calling CreateBookmark

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I have a NativeActivity and i'm creating a Bookmark in the Execute method so that I know where I was in the workflow. The reason why i'm creating a bookmark is that er not enough stock is for an article, so I need to ask to the user if I wants another article that is on stock.

The user would get a question to select one of the alternative articles that are on stock. To get the alternative articles, I need to get them with original articlenumber from the workflow.

I use ASP .NET MVC so I don't have the articlenumber anymore because it is stateless. The Workflow won't come in the completed event so I can't read the OutArguments. I need to know how I pass a parameter(s) with a bookmark.

Thanks

```
public sealed class AskAlternative : NativeActivity
{
    public OutArgument<string> ArticleNumber { get; set; }

    protected override bool CanInduceIdle { get { return true; } }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        context.CreateBookmark(ShoppingCartFlowActivityViews.AskAlternative.ToString(), Continue);
    }

    void Continue(NativeActivityContext context, Bookmark bookmark, object obj)
    {
        var tuple = (Tuple<string>)obj;

        context.SetValue(ArticleNumber, tuple.Item1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't add parameters to a bookmark. Instead you normally create a bookmark and then pass the bookmark, or just its name, along with any other data required to whoever will be resuming the bookmark. Often this involves an activity or workflow extension but this isn't a must have.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that? I need the ArticleNumber back in my Application. See the example above.